# Jumping to a specific iteration "for loops" in python

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

```
myList = [0,1,2,3]
for anIndex in myList:
    print(anIndex)
```

Is there a way in Python to jump to a specific time in a loop, execute, then break out after that single iteration?

```
single_iteration_loop(2)
## 2
```

Comment: Do you want `myList[2]`?

Comment: The straightforward answer is to only loop over the indexes you actually care about: `for anIndex in [2]`:

Comment: Move the loop body into a function, then invoke that function both in the loop and in the special single iteration.

Comment: The answer is no. But there might be a good solution to the _real_ problem you're trying to solve...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
def some_for(check_func):
    for i, v in enumerate([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]):
        if check_func(i, v):
            print(i, v)
            break


def single_iteration_loop(it):
    some_for(lambda i, v: i == it)


single_iteration_loop(3)
```

Output:

```
3 3
```

Comment: Look at `itertools.islice`.

Comment: @Daniel yes thanks. Just to make things clear, what goes underneath, i did this manually.

Answer (score 1):

A single index "iteration" is single index access, use that:

```
myList = [0,1,2,3]
print(mylist[2])
```

If you just want some of the items in the list...just iterate over them:

```
my_list = [0,1,2,3]
my_useful_indexes = [2, 3]
for i in my_useful_indexes:
    print(my_list[i])
```